# Resize the infoWindow box Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

The default infoWindow size is way too big for me.  I want it to be much smaller can I can't figure out how to do it.  I've tried setting a `maxWidth` parameter on my `infoWindow` constructor like this

```js
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({'maxWidth':'10px'});
```

and setting the CSS width like this

```js
<style type="text/css">
#infoWindow {
    width: 10px;
}
</style>
```

but that only seems to change the size of the text wrapping, not the actual box.  How do I change the size of the `infoWindow` box?

Here is my code.

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    #infoWindow {
        width: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var cityList = [
    ['Chicago', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 1],
    ['Illinois', 40.797177,-89.406738, 2]
    ];

    var demoCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41,-87);

    var map;
    function initialize()
    {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: demoCenter,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        addMarkers();
    }

    function addMarkers()
    {
        var marker, i;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({'maxWidth':'10px'});
        for (i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++)
        {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]),
                map: map,
                title: cityList[i][0]
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                var contentString = '<div id="infoWindow">'
                    +'<div id="bodyContent">'
                    +'<p>'
                    + "This location is:<br>"
                    + marker.title
                    +'</p>'
                    +'</div>'
                    + '</div>';
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
                })(marker, i));
            }
        }

</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
                <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also possible problem: the value of `maxWidth` is supposed to be a number (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions), but `'10px'` is a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The native infoWindow has a minimum size.  If it is to big for you, you need to look at using an alternative solution like  [infoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html) or [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html)

Comment: What is a minimum size of native infoWindow?

Comment: looks like ~ 200px - [how to shrink the infoWindow](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/c5ba914f3c3eb02/f939f81d732086df) - [how to change the size of infowindow](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/e77b0f16e53ae38/2bc1311b01314e80)

Answer (score 1):

1. your CSS section doesn't do anything because `var infoWindow` is not the same as `<div id="infoWindow">`
2. The [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions) says:

> **maxWidth**: Maximum width of the infowindow, regardless of content's width. This value is only considered if it is set before a call to
>   open. To change the maximum width when changing content, call close,
>   setOptions, and then open.

Also what Larry, (geocodezip), said. (he types faster than me)  ;-)