# Size of infoWindow in google maps api v3. What is the right solution?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have need to change width and height of google maps infoWindow and I saw this topic [Google Map .InfoWindow Set Height and Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858898/google-map-infowindow-set-height-and-width). I found that the solutions from it doesn't work. Even standart `infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: '50px'})` isn't going to work.

So what is a solution? How to change width and height of infoWindow?

Comment: 50 px is too small. See replies to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102285/resize-the-infowindow-box-google-maps-api-v3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works for me:

```
new google.maps.InfoWindow({ maxWidth: 320 });
```

Remove the ' ' and the px specifier and I believe it will work for you too.

Comment: I set new google.maps.InfoWindow({ maxWidth: 150 }); It doesn't work either. It has the exactly same size.

Comment: It works but changes the width of the content. I need to change the infoWindow.

Answer (score 24):

I always use a div inside the infowindow and it works best for me.  Then you just set the size of the div via css.

Here is a link. :

[Google Maps API v3: InfoWindow not sizing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554893/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-not-sizing-correctly)

Comment: Just to let you know, this is the better answer and should have been treated as such. Add a div inside the infowindow object, i.e. var InfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "DIV HERE" });

Answer (score 9):

The **GoogleMaps-API** generates the class "`gm-style-iw`" around the `InfoWindow`. So you can simply change the size by **CSS**, without the need of extra markup:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});


.gm-style-iw {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have added and it is working

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content:'<div style="width:200px; height:100px">Some text</div>'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I would like to add a responsive solution. This will adapt nicely on small devices.

```
@media (max-width: 413px) {
// Set gm container to screen width leaving 20px pad on each side
  .gm-style-iw {
    width: calc(100vw - 40px)!important;
    min-width: unset!important;
    max-width: unset!important;
  }

  // Next is the container Div that you create on your infoWindow function
  // on google example var contentString = '<div id="content">'+

  .your-main-container-class {
    width: calc(100vw - 80px);
    padding: 8px 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

Then for bigger screens just set your width as google suggest

```
.your-main-container-class{
  width: 316px; // Your desire width
  padding: 8px 0 8px 8px; // Play with padding if you have a custom close button
}
```

UPDATE 2023

with everyday growing CSS, now we could use:

> (depending on the browser support you need to provide, always check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/))

```
width: min(100%, 316px);
margin-inline: auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "",
    maxWidth: 200 ,
    maxHeight: 400
});
```

Comment: Your answer should contains an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Comment: The width & height of the ifowindow can be set by using maxWidth and maxHeight

Comment: if u want to add style use iwContent{width:400px;}

Comment: Use the Edit button to improve your answer, instead of writing a comment. That way you have more chances getting upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I found that unless I forced the style with `!important`, it didn't work. So:

```
.gm-style-iw {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px !important;
}
```