# Checking for InfoWindow size in google map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

We have created a widget using google map in which we can show custom marker and custom text in info window, and then this widget can be used with different templates. Now the problem is that different templates can have different block sizes for widgets sometime they are full width sometimes they are just some 100 pixels. I just want to know if we can know the InfoWindow size some how and then on the basis of that If infoWindo size si bigget then the widget size then we will redirect the user on a detail page with bigger map.

Can any one suggest me how to get the infoWindow size:

Following is the snippet of how we are generating map and infoWindo:

```
var mapConf = {
    center: somePoint,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom:  12
},
markerData = {
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: somePoint,
    title: 'Some random title'
},
iconConf = getMarkerIcon($markerTypeIcon || 'hollowPin', {
    fill: getColor($color_one)
}) ;

if( iconConf ) {
    iconConf.fillColor = iconConf.fill;
    iconConf.strokeColor = iconConf.stroke;
    markerData.icon = iconConf;
}

// create the map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-widget'), mapConf);

// create infowindow
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

// create marker
marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerData);

marker.setMap(map);

var strContent = '<div id="content" style="width:170px; height: 100%;">' +
                        '<div id="add1">' +
                            '<b>'+ _config.dataName.getValue +'</b><br>' + _config.addressInfo +'</div>' +
                        '<div id="dataLink">' +
                            '<a onclick="javascript: window.parent.location.href='+ _config.strLink +'\'">GO</a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';

// set up property info window
markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: strContent,
      position: somePoint,
      maxWidth:600
});

// add click event for marker to show info window
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    markerInfoWindow.open(map, this);
});
```

Comment: have you tried this *new google.maps.InfoWindow({ maxWidth: 320 });*

Comment: @Atula I don want to set width I want to detect what is the size of the the InfoWindow so that I can compare the size of my widget div and redirect user if there is not much space available to open InfoWindow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try get size of **div element**

```
// set up property info window

    markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: strContent,
          position: somePoint,
          maxWidth:600
    });

// add click event for marker to show info window

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        maxWidth = document.getElementById('map-widget').offsetWidth; 
       // Or maxWidth = $('#map-widget').width();
        markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: strContent,
              position: somePoint,
              maxWidth: maxWidth
        });
        markerInfoWindow.open(map, this);
    });
```

Comment: I don't want to adjust InfoWindow sizeI just want to know the size of and if its larger then the widget size then want to redirect user to more detailed page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add), `maxWidth` specifies the maximum width of the info window in pixels. By default, an info window expands to fit its content, and auto-wraps text if the info window fills the map. If you add a `maxWidth` the info window will auto-wrap to enforce the specified width. If it reaches the maximum width and there is vertical room on the screen, the info window may expand vertically.

Then if you wish to explicitly size the content, you can put it in a `<div>` element and style the `<div>` with CSS. You can use CSS to enable scrolling too. Note that if you do not enable scrolling and the content exceeds the space available in the info window, the content may spill out of the info window.

Try to add div inside your infowindow.

```
<div class="myinfowindow"> </div>
```

Then set the size using css.

```
.myinfowindow{
width:500px;
height:100px;
}
```

Check also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115183/size-of-infowindow-in-google-maps-api-v3-what-is-the-right-solution) for more information.

Comment: I think you are getting me wrong I don't want infoWindow to fit I want to detect the size of window so that I can compare it with widget div and see if its size is appropriate to fit in there else will redirect user to a more detailed page where map can be of bigger size.

Comment: By default, info window expands itself to fit the content inside of it. Unless you expand it using the width. So I think for you to know the size of it,maybe you should set its size by yourself.

Comment: Well I appreciate the help but how setting the size will help me in getting the size can you please try explain it, which will be more helpful or adding an answer might be more appropriate :D